# Check if a line is handled by "try catch"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

is there a tool or so to check in Visual Studio if a line is handled by a "try catch" block?
Of course not only in the method of the line. All calling Methods to.

regards Chris

Comment: I use my eyes. What's the question here? Every line should *not* be covered by a try-catch block. You should only catch errors that you're actually able to handle. Let the rest of the bubble up.

Comment: I think he's looking for some tool that looks at a line of code, if it's a method or property call uses the documentation to determine if that line can throw an exception.  If it can, ensure that he is catching that exception type.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is not.  There's a couple reasons why this would be impossible/non-trivial in .NET.  The first of which is that it is impossible to ensure a line throws an exception without "decompiling" the bytecode of the method.  Unlike in Java, .NET does not provide for a language specification which specifies what exceptions are thrown.  There is a documentation spec, but there's no enforcements that the documentation is filled out or correct.  In java you have to declare what exceptions a method can throw which is what makes this possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper used to have a plugin called [Exceptional](http://exceptionalplugin.codeplex.com/) that tried to do something similar. It stopped at R#5.1, but you might be able to reanimate it.